# can not yum install anything on AWS RHEL-7.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum

I am new user to AWS. I tried to install some software on by using yum,
but it always return things like this :

```
[ec2-user@ip-173-32-39-168 yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that RHEL does not have `python-pip` in its default repository. The most common thing to do it to install the EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprize Linux) repository which contains additional common packages, such as `python-pip`. The EPEL repo is mainted by the Fedora Team. It is widely trusted.

### Enable the EPEL Repo:

```
$ sudo yum install wget
$ wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm
```

### Installing python-pip

```
$ sudo yum install python-pip
```